# How to present sent and received SMS in single ListView in android

Tags: android, listview, sms, chat

I am developing an android SMS application. I can send and receive SMS  through my application. I want to show SMS in single listview. I want to know that whether an SMS is
"Sent SMS" or "Received SMS" . How can i check this?? Then update listview SMS as in chat.
Any idea ,tutorial,code snippet will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're querying sms contents by query, you could use `type` column to determine if the sms is sent.

Found in another stackoverflow response, you could look here to see how they do it:
http://gbandroid.googlecode.com/svn-history/r46/trunk/MobileSpy/src/org/ddth/android/monitor/observer/AndroidSmsWatcher.java

Comment: Actually its a private SMS app. I am sending and receiving Sms , Storing them in SQLite database , then i want to retreive them and show in ListView as i described earlier.

Comment: A couple simple options: 1. Add a column to your db table to denote Sent or Received. 2. Keep two separate tables in your db; one for Sent messages and one for Received.